# PHP - Why is it not possible to use ~PHP_INT_MAX as a default argument

Tags: php

I'm wrote a function in which I was using `PHP_INT_MAX` and `~PHP_INT_MAX` as the default arguments but I ended up getting a syntax error for '~'. The declaration is:

```
public static function isNumberValid($number, $lowerbound = ~PHP_INT_MAX, $upperbound = PHP_INT_MAX)
```

I fixed it by making `$lowerbownd = null` in the declaration and then setting it in the body and now it works perfectly fine:

```
if (is_null($lowerbound)){
    $lowerbound = ~PHP_INT_MAX;
}
```

I was just wondering why that is..

Comment: Funny thing is that php.net alone refers to PHP_INT_MAX as _Predefined Constant_ (http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php) and yet in regards to default argument values it states _the default value must be a constant expression_ :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default value of an optional variable has to be constant, like the initial value of variables or constants in a class, for example. `~PHP_INT_MAX` is not a constant, it’s an expression. (You can’t use, say, `2 + 2`, either.)

[There<s>’s</s> was an RFC relating to this.](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/const_scalar_expressions)

Comment: PHP.net says: `The default value must be a constant expression, not (for example) a variable, a class member or a function call.`

Answer (score 4):

The default value of an argument has to be a constant. If you want to use `~PHP_INT_MAX` you can define another constant with that value and use this constant:

```
define('PHP_INT_MIN', ~PHP_INT_MAX);

public static function isNumberValid($number, $lowerbound = PHP_INT_MIN, $upperbound = PHP_INT_MAX)
```

Comment: Slightly related: Is there a specific reason, why the exact same number as `PHP_INT_MIN` [expressed as literal is of type double](http://codepad.org/EB40Vy7p), instead of integer, or is this just a bug in PHP?

Answer (score 2):

Default values for function parameters must be a constant value. They cannot be an expression. Even though PHP_INT_MAX is a compiled-in-value and available to the compiler immediately, you're still causing that to be an expression by doing the bit-wise NOT operation.

```
function foo ($x = PHP_INT_MAX) { echo 'this is ok'; }
function bar ($x = ~PHP_INT_MAX) { echo 'this is NOT ok'; }
```